# How to show the color in the ticks area grid in Google charts library

Tags: laravel, google-visualization

I want to have different color for each ticks.. tried this but not working.
Right now we can only change the colour of the entire background area of the chart but Cant customise it to specific ticks area

```
vAxis: {
        title: 'Score',ticks: [{v:32, color:'red'}, {v:64, f:'blue'}],
      `}
```

This is the goal I want to achieve
[image]

Comment: This is highly unclear. Voted to close this question!

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060091/5090771)...

Comment: yes, please. Still not found the solution

Comment: the answer I shared didn't help? will you please clarify exactly what you need?

Comment: So I want the area of each tick to be coloured. Right now we can only change the colour of the entire background area of the chart but Cant customize it to specific ticks area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: I want to do like this]

Finally able to do with using `stepped area` chart in the combo chart from the Google library...
where the values for each stepped area is the value for ticks.

Here is the link for [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/VikasRinvi/uwba6Ljy/1/)